# How to get max value of multiple column in a single row?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

trying to get max value of months column in a single row

for example i want to get max value from jan~ dec from first column which is currently 5 is the max value

preferably do it in laravel

[image]

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the PHP [max](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) function

To get the month name(s) (remember more than one month could have the maximum value), you'll need to implement a loop.

```php
$max_day = max(
    $record->jan,
    $record->feb,
    $record->mar,
    $record->apr,
    $record->may,
    $record->jun,
    $record->jul,
    $record->aug,
    $record->sep,
    $record->oct,
    $record->nov,
    $record->dec
);

$columns = [
    'jan' => 'January',
    'feb' => 'February',
    'mar' => 'March',
    'apr' => 'April',
    'may' => 'May',
    'jun' => 'June',
    'jul' => 'July',
    'aug' => 'August',
    'sep' => 'September',
    'oct' => 'October',
    'nov' => 'November',
    'dec' => 'December',
];

$max_months = [];

foreach ($columns as $column_name => $month_name) {
    if ($record->{$column_name} === $max_day) {
        $max_months[] = $month_name;
    }
}

// $max_months e.g. ['January', 'February']
```